# ssh banner per user

Tags: ssh, login, sshd

I want to notify a certain user to call me, the admin, since I disabled his account. I could set `/etc/issue.net`, but this is shown to all login attempts. Is there a way to restrict a message/banner to a certain user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-enable the user's login, but change the account's shell to a script which outputs the message and exits.

Comment: My Linux (Centos, a Redhat clone) uses /sbin/nologin as a shell in these situations, which reads /etc/nologin.txt as a message

Comment: The banner is displayed before connection, and though your answer satisfies the OP, it's not what was asked. Any idea about per-user banner? (and not motd)